# How to push an existing sub-document into an embedded array in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to determine if the following use case is feasible in MongoDB 3.4: I have a collection containing documents with a schema similar to this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    "data": {
        "fname": "John",
        "lname": "Doe"
    },
    "history": []
}
```

The `data` field is meant to hold the current state of the entity and the `history` array is meant to hold the most recent versions of it (accounting for the max document size and for querying purposes).

When an update operation is issued from application logic, I would like to `$push` the `data` field into the `history` array and the replace it with the new state of the entity. I haven't been able to find anything about this on the MongoDB docs and every question I found on `SO` deals with pushing a totally new object into an array, not "moving" an existing field's value.
Is it possible to reference a document field in a `$push` operation like this?

Comment: I believe your application code should take care of it. In the steps as 1 ) read the "data" ( database read), 2) populate the histroy ( push) 3) add the new state of "data" ( local object in application) and finally store ( database operation again). Use Spring data for this case

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper I understand where you might be coming from here and agree for the most part. What I'm trying to do here is take advantage of the update-in-place feature in `MongoDB` so the whole operation is performed atomically. I ended up doing something very similar to what @kittu posted. See his answer below. I'm using `C#`, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
db.collection.update({"_id": "1234"}, {"$set": {"data": {"data-value"}}}, {"$push": {"history": {"history-value"}})
```

You can write like this, it will automatically push the value into history, and change the  data to present state.